# Why does +++x gives an error message when +x++ works fine?

Tags: javascript

```
var x = null;
```

`+++x` generates a `ReferenceError`, but when I do the same using postfix increment operator `+x++`, it works just fine.

Comment: why do u want to increace a null  ??? any way

Comment: Not worked on my chrome(14.0.835) browser.

Comment: In Chrome both give `ReferenceError`

Comment: @Qchmqs +x initializes `x` to 0 if `x` is `null`

Comment: @Qchmqs: for the sake of the example?

Comment: WHy You Want to increase a NULL value  ???
this is my question !!!

Comment: i know (+X) will do that but why not x = 0 ; ???it's cleaner and simpler

Comment: if u used the x= 0 ; 
x will be initalized with a integer type that will accept the ++x oprator while ++(+x)
is like a ++(+null)

Comment: @lostyzd Updated the question now. Removed the parentheses to make the postfix increment operator work.

Answer (score 5):

The `LeftHandSideExpression` for the `++` operator must not be a number. For instance

```
1++;
```

will fail with the same error (invalid increment operand). You can only apply the pre- and postincrement operators on variables/identifiers/expressions.

Since the `+` sign casts the `null value` into a number (0), you got the same outcome.

Examples:

```
var foo = null,
    bar = 5;

foo++;    // 0
0++;      // invalid increment operand
null++;   // invalid increment operand
(+bar)++  // invalid increment operand
foo++ +2; // 2
```

Comment: Please check the updated question. I removed the parentheses and the postfix increment operator works in all browsers, while the prefix increment does not work.

Answer (score 1):

+x++ is split into two steps:

- +x initialises x to 0, so it's no longer null.
- x++ then increments x, which works since x is no longer null.

+++x is also split into two steps, but in a particular order:

- ++x is evaluated first, which throws the exception because x is null.
- +x would then be evaluated, except you've already had an exception.

I think your assumption was that +++x would be parsed as ++(+x), but it's actually parsed as +(++x). It's an ambiguous-looking syntax, the language designers had to pick one of the two ways to parse it, and from your point of view they chose "the other one".

To be honest, there's absolutely no value in formatting your code this way anyway - all you end up with is dubious-looking code which is destined to confuse people.

Comment: ++x = 1 when x is null. it does not throw any exception.

Comment: @Narenda, I think you're assuming that x is an integer. Integers cannot *ever* be null (code of "int x;" would automatically initialise x as 0). In this case, we're dealing with a custom reference type (rather than a builtin value type) which happens to implement the increment operator. Variables of such types *can* be set to null, and ++x in such a case *would* throw an exception.

Comment: I simply declare `var x = null;` and then i do `++x`, it returns `1`.

Answer (score 0):

if u used the x= 0 ; 
x will be initalized with a integer type that will accept the ++x operator while ++(+x)
is like a ++(+null)
so better try to change to X = 0 ;